# Частично не включаются @media запросы

Tags: css

[image: Картинка ошибки]
Здравствуйте уважаемые участники сообщества!
сверстал страницу но после проверки столкнулся с неприятным моментом (как на меня не стандартным)
частично не подключаются медиа запросы стилей, то есть например у меня есть стиль:

```
    .list_img img {
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    width: 79%;
    margin-top: 7%;
    margin-left: 14%;
}
```

при изменении экрана появляется медиа запрос (но он не включен как будто второстепенный "зачеркнутый")
Вот он:

```
    @media (max-width: 768px)
.list_img img {
    width: 55%;
    margin-top: 1%;
    margin-left: 0%;
}
```

Но при этом, другие стили которые добавлены в этот запрос (768) включаются, то есть это как будто какой то плавающий момент.
И таким образом по всей верстке моментами не включается часть стилей.
медиа находиться в файле с стилями для этой страницы, так же делал отдельный файл для мобильных стилей не помогает.

Comment: `@media` подключается в отдельным файле ? ниже или выше стандартного коду

Comment: Здравствуйте, медиа перекинул в основной фай, выше основного кода (почти, пару стилей выше @media)

Comment: `@media` запрос должен быть всегда в конце `css-файла`, + от максимального размера до минимального, если в другом `css-файле' то он должен подключатся после основного

Comment: Сейчас попробую! Спасибо

Comment: Все сработало. Спасибо за помощь!